# C2594 : Ambiguous Conversion with COM Object

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an ATL class that I'm trying to implement a cast operator for each interface that it implements. The class is a mock representing a real object.

```
class CMock :
  public IDispatchImpl<Interface1 ...>
  public IDispatchImpl<Interface2 ...>
```

The ATL COM Mapping is as follows:

```
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMock)
  // Resolve ambiguity by exposing Interface1 through Interface2
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY2(Interface1, Interface2)
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(Interface)
END_COM_MAP()
```

I then have overloaded the cast operators for `Interface1*` and `Interface2*`

```
operator Interface1* () 
{ 
  Interface1* pInterface1;
  if(FAILED(this->QueryInterface(IID_Interface1, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pInterface1)))
     return nullptr;
  return pInterface1;
}
// Repeat for IInterface2
```

Despite the overloaded cast operators, I'm still getting an ambiguous error when trying to cast to any interface that is exposed through another.

`error C2594: 'argument' : ambiguous conversions from 'CMock *' to 'Interface1 *'`

```
int main()
{
   CComPtr<CMock> mock = new CComObject<CMock>();

   Interface1* pInterface1 = mock; // Error C2594
   Interface2* pInterface2 = mock; // compiles OK.
   return 0;
}
```

I understand WHY the ambiguous conversions are there, but I'm confused as to why the compiler is even looking at those when I define a custom cast operator. Is there anyway to define the cast operator such that the compiler will ignore the other conversion possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your defining cast operator does not help here since you are defining it on `CMock` class, while the problem happens with `CComPtr<CMock>`, which is a wrapper on top of `CMock*`. So the operator is not helpful, however it does not need to help.

Skipping other issues in your snippets (and there are a few of them), you eventually need the following:

If you have a raw pointer, such as `CMock*` or `CComObject<CMock>*` then you can cast using C++ cast operators, e.g.

```
Interface1* pInterface1 = (Interface*) (CMock*) mock;
```

If you have an interface pointer of your object, not the native pointer, then you can get your interface using `QueryInterface` or `CComQIPtr`.

```
CComQIPtr<Interface1> pInterface1 = mock; // or, "... = (Interface2*) mock;"
                                 // to possibly resolve `IUnknown*` ambiguities
```

Comment: Those C-style casts are sooo horrible in such scenarios. Sometimes they guarantee very long debugging.

Comment: @sharptooth: they are extremely clear and readable. Never gave me any trouble. Then when they are static casts, compiler issues an error when conversion is not available.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to get an error if I copy-paste and then underedit some code. C-style casts will just compile.

Comment: `(CMock*) mock;` won't compile when conversion is not avaiable. `static_cast<CMock*>(mock)` is too bulky to read. Bottom line, C style casts still rule.

Comment: `(CMock*)` will not compile but `(Interface*)` can compile when it should not. Btw you don't need `(CMock*)` cast in the first place - just access `.p` of the smart pointer and then pass that into `static_cast<Interface*>`.

Comment: Cast is elegant, and accessing `.p` is not, the whole idea of smart template is to hide that `p`. Cast is a hint to help use the object in a proper way, whereas touching the inner stuff is exactly the opposite - resolving the issue by doing what is not supposed to be done.

Comment: Actually it's a design bug in `CComPtr` that there's no accessor method that would explicitly retrieve the raw pointer.

Comment: Microsoft recommend a double `static_cast`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xata8be.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396